# How are member types implemented?

Tags: c++

I'm looking at this resource:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

For example, the iterator *member type* on class vector.

Would a "member type" simply be implemented as a typedef or something similar in the vector class? It is not clear to me what "member type" actually means, and I've looked at a couple C++ textbooks, they don't even mention this phrase at all.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The C++ Standard does not use this phrase either. Instead, it would call it a *nested type name* (§9.9).

There are four ways to get one:

```
class C
{
public:
   typedef int int_type;       // as a nested typedef-name
   using float_type = float;   // C++11: typedef-name declared using 'using'

   class inner_type { /*...*/ };   // as a nested class or struct

   enum enum_type { one, two, three };  // nested enum (or 'enum class' in C++11)
};
```

Nested type names are defined in class scope, and in order to refer to them from outside that scope, name qualification is required:

```
int_type     a1;          // error, 'int_type' not known
C::int_type  a2;          // OK
C::enum_type a3 = C::one; // OK
```

Comment: I wish every answer on this website was provided with such clarity, simplicity and efficiency. Thank you.

Comment: @johnbakers I wish too !

Comment: Do member types must be implemented as part of a std container class? Is this part of the standard? How exactly are they useful?

Comment: Found answers to my questions above (Couldn't edit the above comment due to some five minute rule) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714566/what-do-member-types-mean-in-vectors. Never knew consciously that I was using a member type when I was using an iterator of a container class before!

Answer (score 4):

Member type simply stands for a type that is a member(of that class). It could be a `typedef` as you say (in the case of `vector`it is likely to be `T*`) or it could be nested `class` (or `struct`).

Answer (score 2):

Member type may refer to 'nested class' or 'nested structure'.
It means class inside another class. If you want to refer text books then search for 'nested classes'.