# return type is a variable in a class

Tags: c++

I am looking the C++ reference, and I see the

```
template <size_t I, class... Types>
typename tuple_element< I, tuple<Types...> >::type const& get(const tuple<Types...>& tpl) noexcept;
```

and what I cannot understand is the the return type, what does the `typename tuple_element< I, tuple<Types...> >::type const&` means?

My interpertation is that it return a const reference to a general type of `tuple_element::type` , but I think that the `tuple_element::type` is like below

```
Class A{
  public:
      int B;
}
A::B = .........;
```

but why it can be used as a type? I cannot understand it.

Comment: It's a struct, but `tuple_element::type` is not like the `B` in your class. Your `B` is a data member, but `type` of `tuple_element` is a nested typedef.

Comment: Can you be more clear and provide it as a answer? Thx.

Comment: This may be helpful: [How are member types implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037392/how-are-member-types-implemented/14037521)

Comment: That's precisely the type of issues I do not like in C++: all these template parameter dependent typedefs really obscure the code. My advise would be to avoid such constructs in your own code as much as you can, it will be much more readable for it (and the compiler error messages will be as well).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `type` in `typename tuple_element< I, tuple<Types...> >::type` is not a variable. It is a type within another type (`tuple_element< I, tuple<Types...> >`).

Referencing a type within another type can be done by using `::`, the scope resolution operator, just as you do when referencing a variable or function within a class or a namespace.

Example:

```
namespace my_namespace {

    struct my_type {
        typedef int some_type;  // some_type here is an alias for int (both are types)
    };   

}

int main() {
    my_namespace::my_type::some_type some_variable;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here, your class member is not a variable, but a type defined in the scope of the class. If you want a simple example :

```
struct myClass
{
    typedef int myIntType;
};
```

you can write:

```
myClass::myIntType i = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

From `tuple_element` [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element):

> ### Member types:
>
> ```
> type: the type of Ith element of the tuple, where I is in [0, sizeof...(Types))
> ```
>
> ### Possible implementation:
>
> ```
> template< std::size_t I, class T >
> struct tuple_element;
>  
> // recursive case
> template< std::size_t I, class Head, class... Tail >
> struct tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Head, Tail...>>
>     : std::tuple_element<I-1, std::tuple<Tail...>> { };
>  
> // base case
> template< class Head, class... Tail >
> struct tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Head, Tail...>> {
>    typedef Head type;
> };
> ```